# using float + Lambda Expressions C#

Tags: c#, lambda

```
var distances = new Dictionary<char, float>();
var nodes = new List<char>();
```

I have this line to find the smallest distance

```
nodes.Sort((x, y) => distances[x] - distances[y]);
```

When I use `int` it works well, but when I used `float` I got a message

> cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer' because it is not a
>   delegate type

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, your original program is a bad programming practice when the values are integers.  It works for chars, but I would avoid this bad programming practice.

The delegate you pass to the sort function must have a number of properties; in particular it must return a negative int if x is smaller than y, a positive int if x is greater than y, and zero if they are equal. Your original lambda does not do that for integer values.  (See if you can find two integers x and y such that x is smaller than y but x - y is positive.)

The delegate must also impose a *total order*. In a total order:

- Transitivity must hold. If A == B and B == C then A must equal C. If A < B and B < C then A must be smaller than C. And so on.
- It must be antisymmetric. That is, if A < B then B > A, and so on.

Subtraction does not meet these conditions in integers. The correct code is to actually write a comparison.

```
nodes.Sort((x, y) => x < y ? -1 : (x > y ? 1 : 0));
```

That then works well for chars and floats, *provided there are no NaNs*. If you have NaNs then you need to do extra work to impose a total order.

I would also point out that this ordinal comparison on chars is usually not the comparison you want.  Sure, this will correctly note that `e` is smaller than `z`, but simple ordinal comparison also says that `z` is smaller than `é`, which is likely not what you want. Character ordering depends on culture; are you sure you want to order by the order that the Unicode committee just happened to impose?

For more on this topic see my series of articles; it begins here:

http://ericlippert.com/2011/01/20/bad-comparisons-part-one/

Answer (score 8):

You can't convert your lambda expression into a `Comparison<char>` (which is what you want) because it returns a `float` - you've effectively got a `Func<char, char, float>` there, whereas `Comparison<char>` is closer to `Func<char, char, int>`.

The simplest approach is to use [`float.CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74z9b11e(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
nodes.Sort((x, y) => distances[x].CompareTo(distances[y]));
```

Or if you don't need to sort in-place, you could use LINQ:

```
var sorted = nodes.OrderBy(x => distances[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformulate the lambda expression as follows.

```
nodes.Sort((x, y) =>
  {
    float Result = distances[x] - distances[y];
    if ( Result > 0.0f )
      return 1;
    else if ( Result < 0.0f )
      return -1;
    else
      return 0;
  });
```

Comment: That's a lot more work than using `float.CompareTo` :)

Comment: It is bizarre to me that you'd compute the less-than relation by first subtracting and then comparing with zero; you're using a less-than operator on floats, so why not simply use it on the original floats?